# An item is not getting clicked

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate sample data. In an Excel sheet, there is the name of the shop and shop location. First, the shop_location is entered and then the shops in the locality are shown. My code is supposed to click on the shop name specified in the Excel sheet.
The code succeeds in searching the location but then after it goes to the page where the different shops are present, it fails to click on the shop which will take it to the shop's webpage.
I used selenium to automate.

```py
try:
    shop_link_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f'//a[text()="shop_name"]/@href')))
    print(shop_link_element)
    shop_link_element.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print(f"Shop Name: {shop_name}, Shop Location: {shop_location}, Status: Not found on the shop page")

except TimeoutException:
    print(f"Shop Name: {shop_name}, Shop Location: {shop_location}, Status: Not found in search results")
```

This is the part i suspect doesn't work.